# Dynamic label with Handler

Tags: vb.net, winforms, event-handling, tags, addhandler

I have labels that are dynamically added on to the form with each of them having a link under their tag.
I also have the `AddHandler lbTitle.Click` to the dynamic labels, but when I try to do this, it doesn't work:

```
Private Sub lbTitle_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Process.Start(e.Tag)
End Sub
```

Because

> 'tag' is not a member of 'System.EventArgs'

How can I solve this so that when someone clicks on of the dynamically added labels, it would launch the url from the label's tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an event handler, you need the [`AddressOf` Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y72ewk2b.aspx)

```
AddHandler lbTitle.Click, AddressOf lbTitle_Click
```

To get the reference to your `Label` in the event handler, you can use the `sender` argument:

```
Private Sub lbTitle_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim label = DirectCast(sender, Label)
    Process.Start(label.Tag.ToString())
End Sub
```

Comment: I already had the AddressOf Operator, but I didn't put in the whole line. But your answer is still helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The sender argument is the label, but you will need to cast it to the `Label` type before you can access its `Tag` property.

```
Process.Start(CType(sender, Label).Tag)
```

Or, to handle any type of control, you could cast it to the base Control type, instead:

```
Process.Start(CType(sender, Control).Tag)
```